# libpq outputs notices into the terminal

Tags: c, postgresql, libpq

I'm writing a library that wraps libpq in C. When I execute a query like `DROP SCHEMA IF EXISTS bob`, and `bob` doesn't exist, libpq outputs

```
"NOTICE:  schema "bob" does not exist, skipping"
```

into my terminal, but then succeeds. Similarly, if I create a table with `id serial primary key` it prints a notice that it auto-generated a sequence.

How do I stop it printing this into the terminal? I have functions in my library to obtain such information, if the user needs it, but it should not just output into the terminal like this.

I didn't see anything in the documentation for `PQexecParams()`, or `PQconnectdb()` etc.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

See [libpq - notice processing](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/libpq-notice-processing.html) in the manual. You need to supply a notice processor to replace the default one.

> The default notice processor is simply:
>
> ```
> static void
> defaultNoticeProcessor(void *arg, const char *message)
> {
>     fprintf(stderr, "%s", message);
> }
> ```

Comment: Interesting, thanks, I'll give this a shot! Seems kinda weird really, given this information is available via PQerrorMessage() and PQresultErrorMessage() :)

Comment: Hah, apparently notices and warnings aren't available from those functions I mention. I wonder what PGRES_NONFATAL_ERROR is then.

Answer (score 0):

One option is to change it's stdout (and/or stderr).

Comment: I actually think it's stderr, though I'm not sure this is what I'm after, unless it's the only way I can do it, which would seem kinda weird. You don't normally expect a C library to output anything unless you've told it to.

Comment: Yeah, I'm not sure. Don't know what would cause it to output that you would be able to change other than redirecting stdout/stderr though.